# Kafka message key is None

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-asyncio

This is the implementation for my Kafka producer and consumer:

```
async def produce(topic_name):
    """Produces data into the Kafka Topic"""
    p = Producer({"bootstrap.servers": BROKER_URL})

    curr_iteration = 0
    while True:
        p.produce(topic_name, f"iteration {curr_iteration}".encode("utf-8"))
        curr_iteration += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


async def consume(topic_name):
    """Consumes data from the Kafka Topic"""
    c = Consumer({"bootstrap.servers": BROKER_URL, "group.id": "0"})
    c.subscribe([topic_name])
    while True:
        message = c.poll(1.0)
        if message is None:
            print("no message received by consumer")
        elif message.error() is not None:
            print(f"error from consumer {message.error()}")
        else:
            print(f"consumed message {message.key()}: {message.value()}")
        await asyncio.sleep(2.5)
```

The `message.key()` is `None` and get the console output as below:

```
consumed message None: b'iteration 1'
consumed message None: b'iteration 8'
consumed message None: b'iteration 12'
consumed message None: b'iteration 15'
```

How do I update the code to get the message key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your produce function like below,

```
p.produce(topic, key="key", value="value")
```

> To initiate sending a message to Kafka, call the `produce` method,
> passing in the message value (which may be `None`) and `optionally a key`, partition, and callback. The produce call will complete immediately
> and does not return a value. A KafkaException will be thrown if the
> message could not be enqueued due to librdkafka’s local produce queue
> being full.

Source :- [clients-confluent-kafka-python](https://docs.confluent.io/clients-confluent-kafka-python/current/overview.html)